# PHP unserialize : everything works fine except one entry

Tags: php, deserialization

I'm trying to unserialize some data stored in mysql.

Everything is okay except ONE field that can't be displayed.

The data :

```
a:4:{
s:7:"prénom";s:6:"Johnny";
s:3:"nom";s:5:"Rocky";
s:12:"NOT WORKING";s:2:"on";
s:7:"opt in2";s:2:"on";
}
```

that I'm calling with

```
<?php $mydata = $result['data']; 
$mydata = unserialize($mydata);
echo $mydata['prénom']; 
echo $mydata['nom']; 
echo $mydata['NOT WORKING']; 
echo $mydata['opt in2']; 
?>
```

"prénom", "nom" and "opt in2" are correctly displayed, but "NOT WORKING" isn't (nothing is displayed). 
What is interesting in the latter is that the number before the string do not match the number of letters, you can see it's written 12 while the string has 11 letters (space included). I tried to change it to 11 but it screws everything.

What is even more fun is that all the values (including "NOT WORKING" can still be properly displayed with something like :

```
<?php foreach($result['data'] as $fieldName => $fieldValue){?>
<?php echo esc_html(strip_tags(wp_kses_stripslashes(ucwords($fieldName)))); ?>
<?php echo esc_html(strip_tags(wp_kses_stripslashes(ucwords($fieldValue)))); ?>
```

Can someone explain me what is happening ? I can't see any logic in here.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try a `var_dump(array_map('bin2hex', array_keys($mydata)))` on the unserialized `$mydata` and show us the result.

Comment: how do you get that string? from some POST form data? are you sure there are no hidden characters in the NOT WORKING string?

Comment: Don't use spaces in array keys. It is allowed, but it could lead to some unwished behaviors - replace with underscores, and retry.

Comment: Thanks moonwave that did the trick! Indeed the behavior is "unwished", as I have several other fields with space in the name and they work good. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @Zatrhus thanks you were also right here, the space between NOT and WORKING was indeed a " " (hum yeah it's still a space but in an editor it looks like an horizontal bracket). It's still strange, because to prevent this kind of issue I carefully copied and pasted the string from mysql.